# Android API Location

Tags: android, api, location, cellid

My app can show network info such as MCC, MNC, LAC, CellID, RXlevel. 
However I want to force my Android to connect to fix cellID or channel (frequency).
Do you know how to do it ?

Thank you so much.

Phong

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to determining the location of the cell tower your phone is communicating with, you can only do this via Android platform APIs with CDMA devices:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/cdma/CdmaCellLocation.html#getBaseStationLatitude()

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/cdma/CdmaCellLocation.html#getBaseStationLongitude()

Be aware that sometimes these APIs will give you an estimate of the cell sector centroid instead of the physical location of the tower.

You can also use the Network location provider.

Register the provider:

`lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);`

And listen for location via the LocationListener:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i(TAG, "New lat: " + location.getLatitude());
    Log.i(TAG, "New long: " + location.getLongitude());
}
```

but you will get both cell and WiFi-based location from this.